# Django - list of objects not visible in DetailView

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I have list of posts on my homepage, which are links to post DetailView. 
Links works correctly, but when i go to DetailView, list is no more visible - i have to go back to home page to choose other post. Element which is showing posts list is located on base.html, correctly passes objects list to home.html, and in post_detail.html list is empty.

[Homepage looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwDAo.png)

[Post DetailView looks like this - posts list is no more visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBQVO.png)

[Inspect view on homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXbOb.png)

[Inepect view on DetailView - ul element is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7egE.png)

**base.html**

```
<body>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="{% url 'blog-home' %}"> home</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a> items</a>
            <ul>
                {% for post in posts %}
                <li>
                    <a href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}"> {{ post.title }}</a>
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </li>       
    </ul>

</div>
<di>
{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}
</div>
</body>
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% for post in posts %}
    <div>
        <a href="#">{{post.title}}</a>
        <p>{{post.content}}</p>
        <p>{{post.date_posted}}</p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

**post_detail.html**

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <div>
        <a href="#">{{object.title}}</a>
        <p>{{object.content}}</p>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import PostListView, PostDetailView
from . import views



urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Post

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'  
    context_object_name = 'posts'

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: detail view is individual view, so you can display all the details of that particular view only, list view is not available there otherwise you have to override the get context data and display it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override the context of your DetailView which display only the data of current instance.

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['other_posts'] = Post.objects.all()
        return context
```